# ORA-01403: no data found IN ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an oracle error executing this PL/SQL in the second line: SELECT ....
But for God's sake ! I've already check if there is some null values

```
IF zocRole IS NOT NULL and devices.unit_id IS NOT NULL THEN                   
   SELECT unit_role_id INTO unitRoleId FROM T_UNIT_ROLE WHERE role_id = zocRole AND unit_id = devices.unit_id;
END IF;
```

Comment: Yes, you have checked whether there are null values, but that does not mean your select will return a  row based on your where conditions

Comment: Always expect the unexpected and put an exception handler around that select to handle it gracefully.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The best way to control the execution in a procedure/function plsql is adding blocks: BEGIN/EXCEPTION.

```
IF zocRole IS NOT NULL AND devices.unit_id IS NOT NULL 
THEN
  BEGIN                 
     SELECT unit_role_id 
     INTO   unitRoleId 
     FROM   T_UNIT_ROLE 
     WHERE  role_id = zocRole 
     AND    unit_id = devices.unit_id
     ;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE||'-'||SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
  END
  ;
END IF
;
```

Comment: Bad practice - this is functionally equivalent to `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL` - all exceptions get swallowed and treated as successful.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, this exception is thrown because your implicit cursor returns no rows.  You would also get an exception if more than one row is returned.

You could instead use an Explicit Cursor [Oracle Documents](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/explicit_cursor.htm) This is really just a named SQL statement (into which you can pass parameters if you like).

You then open the cursor, fetch (each fetch will attempt to retrieve one row) and close.  You can then check whether the fetch returned any data.  It takes slightly longer to code but can look cleaner.

I remember that years ago there was some debate about the relative speed of implicit vs explicit cursors but I've not heard anyone talk about this for a long time so I assume they perform the same